# A complete listing with rev-list

Tags: git, command

I have a clone of a git repository checked out that I use to have atomation collect period metrics (KLOC, etc.)

I collect these metrics once a week, but occasionally I want to go back into time and re-run the metrics (if I add a new metric, or something else in the system changes).

To checkout a particular point in time I use the following command:

```
git checkout `git rev-list -n 1 --before=2012-8-20 master` --force
```

But I find that the rev-list command does not keep up to date.  New revisions that occur after the date I start using this process do not appear in the rev-list command.  If I clone from scratch, I see the additional revisions, but I would prefer not to have to clone the entire repository each time.

Is there an option I am missing on rev-list to have it know all the latest revisions from the master branch?

Comment: I have a feeling theres something else going on here. `rev-list` definitely stays up to date (things like `rebase -i` depend on it...)

Comment: If I do a fresh clone (same clone command as the original that was cloned about two weeks ago) and do a rev-list, the original clone is missing the top items in the rev-list, but the rest of the items are there and identical.

Comment: Now, if I try to do a git checkout in the original repository with a rev-list item that only appears on the newly clones rev-list I get an error:  "fatal: reference is not a tree: 30fad...".  This same command works without incident on the newly cloned repository.

Comment: Do you `git fetch` and `git merge <remote>/<branch>` between running these commands? It just sounds like your local commit history isn't up to date.

Comment: No, did not.  Since this repository is only for collecting metrics, I'll never modify things in this repository-- that being the case, shouldn't a checkout be enough?

Comment: I should also mention that when I first run the checkout command, git warns me that "You are now in 'detached HEAD' state" and git status will tell me I am not on a currently working branch-- not sure if that might be the cause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the deal here is that the revlist is not updated automatically relative to a remote master.  Because of this, I need to add the following commands:

```
git checkout master # to go back onto the master branch
git pull            # to update from the master
```

Now the rev list will be up to date, and I can accurately run:

```
git checkout `git rev-list -n 1 --before=2012-8-20 master` --force
```

Now the above command correctly works as a time machine so I can calculate my code metrics.